# How to use Retrofit for Android to communicate with firebase cloud function?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-functions, retrofit

I would like to send a request from my Android App to Google Firebase using google functions.

Therefore I have defined an API-Interface on the client side like:

```
interface MyApi {
    /**
     * Get the list of the pots from the API
     */
    @GET("/posts")
    fun getPosts(): Observable<List<Post>>

    @POST("/addUser")
    fun addUser(@Query("name") name: String, @Query("token") token: String): Observable<User>
}
```

In the ModelView I send a request using RXJava like:

```
subscription = Observable.fromCallable{ loveDateApi.addUser(name, token) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe( { result -> println("Result: $result") },
                        {error -> println("Error: $error")})
```

The User Object I observe on looks like:

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose

@Entity
data class User(
        @Expose
        @field:PrimaryKey
        val idUser: Int,
        @Expose
        val token: String,
        @Expose
        val name: String,
        @Expose
        val age: Int
)
```

My Network-Module where I provide Retrofit looks like below (just an extract):

´´´

```
@Provides
@Reusable
@JvmStatic
internal fun provideRetrofitInterface(): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build()
}
```

´´´

On the server side, the google cloud function I deployed looks like:

```
exports.addUser = functions.https.onRequest(async (request:any,response:any) => {

  // read parameters from request
  const name = request.query.name
  const token = request.query.token

  const data = {
    name: name,
    age: 30,
    token: token

  }

  // use add if no doc-ID is specified else use set
  const idUser = (await db.collection(collectionUser).add(data)).id

  const newData = {
    idUser: idUser,
  }

  const userRef = db.collection(collectionUser).doc(idUser)
  await userRef.update(newData)
  const newUserRef = await userRef.get()

  response.send(newUserRef.data())
})
```

Using postman to send an request to the cloud functions works, but unfornately not in the client app.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a solution. I added the method **blockingFirst()** in the fromCallabe part, so it looks like that:

```
subscription = Observable.fromCallable{ loveDateApi.addUser(name, token).blockingFirst() }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe( { result -> println("Result: $result") },
                        {error -> println("Error: $error")})
```

Do you know some alternative solutions to RxJava experts out there? ;)